# How to replace current year with present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a dropdownlist in ruby on rails i.e below:

```
<%= f.select :fromyear, (1995..Time.now.year).to_a, :include_blank => {:year => "Select year"} %>
```

Its workin finw, but it shows years from 1995 to 2014 and I want from 2014 to 1995 and also I want to replace with `Time.now.year` i.e `2014`  to `Present` means in dropdownlist `2014` replace with `Present`

Kindly suggest me waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse it

```
    <%= f.select :fromyear, (1995..Time.now.year).to_a.reverse.map! { |e| e == Time.now.year ? "Present" : e }
, :include_blank => {:year => "Select year"} %>
```

Comment: yes, its working fine and Thanks but also I want to replace "2014" with "Present".

Comment: This will pass through "Present" as the value to the server, though, if they select "Present", which means you then need something at the server end to translate "Present" back into a year before saving it to the database or whatever.  It's better to use an array of name-value pairs instead, so that it says "Present" but actually sets the value to "2014".  Change the 'map' (this doesn't need the `!` btw) block to be `.map{|e| e == Time.now.year ? ["Present", e] : [e,e]}`